# WHM and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, whm

First of all sorry for my bad English but isnt my first language.

I own a dedicated server that uses Whm. I installed approximately 30 wordpress in accounts. Suddenly i cant upgrade wordpress via Whm for users. Error message is:

Site Software cPanel::Blogs::WordPress

This is a cPanel packaged module. (v1.04)

Website WordPress

Requires MySQL 5 or newer.

**Could not prepare working directory: No such file or directory**

I used also wpremote.com application but again i am not able to upgrade wordpress. How can i disable wordpress update via Whm and to update them via wordpress administration?

Comment: First... check your mysql requeriments.. on shell -> mysql --version or check on WHM. If not 5.X, you must upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have MySQL v5.x or higher.  In `WHM`, search "MySQL" or under the Software list, look for "MySQL/MariaDB Upgrade".  Once that page is open, select the version you need to upgrade to, hit Next, and this will guide you through the installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue if you install wordpress using WHM or Cpanel. When you install wordpress using WHM/ Cpanel it install default plugin in your wordpress. now when you want to update wordpress version from cpanel this plugin will work as communicator between cpanel/WHM but problem is this plugin will not work if you updated your default theme.

solution simply deactivate your cpanel plugin in your wordpress plugin management and update wordpress setup from your site.